# Sparse matrix algorithms involving data-driven or random access / walk

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms, permutations, random-walk

I am looking for some *well-known* algorithms in which sparse matrix elements are accessed in a *non-structured* way, i.e. row/column depends on a value of another (sparse) matrix/vector element or some variable that is changing throughout the course of the algorithm.

So, if one was to execute an algorithm on a computer or even by hand on a paper, there should *not* be many visible patterns in which *adjacent non-zero elements* in a single row/column are accessed consecutively.

For example, consider a sparse matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 5 \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am not interested in algorithms which contain fairly regular element access patterns like:

- `3 4 5` - accesses the non-zero elements in row 2, in order
- `9 8 0 5 2` - accesses last column in reverse order
- `1 4 7 8` - accesses the superdiagonal, still too structured/regular

but those which involve a lot of "random" patterns like:

- `6 8 1 9 4 3` - accesses only non-zeroes, very interesting
- `3 0 8 5 1 0 0 6` - accessing some zero elements is also interesting
- `8 0 2 5 9` - permutation of a row/column is still interesting enough

(Of course, the exact access pattern depends on the implementation of an algorithm, but I am looking for those algorithms in which there is no obvious way to access, for instance, an entire row/column of a matrix in (reverse) order.)

I would prefer a deterministic algorithm, but randomized ones are also fine.